# Skype for 32 bit computers?

Tags: 18.04, skype

I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS 32 bit and need to know what choices I have, if any. Thanks!

Comment: Skype does not offer 32bit versions of their software.  You would have to use a 64bit install to use skype.

Comment: Thank You! Guess I'll put it on my phone and skip using old 32 bit computer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://web.skype.com on the Chromium browser as per https://www.linuxmadesimple.info/2019/02/how-to-use-skype-on-32-bit-systems-in.html

If you do not have Chromium installed, please step through these CLI commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

If you wish to add it to a menu, add these optional steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peppermintos/p9-release
sudo apt install ice
sudo apt update
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:peppermintos/p9-release
wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Microsoft_Skype_for_Business_logo.svg/2000px-Microsoft_Skype_for_Business_logo.svg.png
```